Do I need to flatten this list in Terraform?
I'm just curious if I am doing this the best way, or am I missing something?
I have a variable defined like so:
variable "acme_cert_requests" {
  type = list(object({
    key_name = string
    certs  = list(object({
      hostname = string
      zone_name = string
    }))
    owner = string
  }))
  description = "List of keys needed for certificate automation."
  nullable    = false
}

I'm passing:
acme_cert_requests = [
  {
    key_name = "test"
    certs  = [
      {
        hostname = "test1.domainB.com"
        zone_name = "domainB.com"
      },
      {
        hostname = "test2.domainA.com"
        zone_name = "domainA.com"
      },
      {
        hostname = "test3.domainA.com"
        zone_name = "domainA.com"
      }      
    ]
    owner = "me@domain.com"
  }
]

I want to get a list of unique zone_name.
I'm using this:
distinct(flatten([for request in var.acme_cert_requests : [
    for zone in request.certs: zone.zone_name]
  ]))

Output:
[
      + "domainB.com",
      + "domainA.com",
]

Without the flatten I end up with a list inside a list. Is there a more direct route to accomplish this?

Your code is Fine, you could look into alternatives with json encode and extract using regex, ... distinct(regexall("\"zone_name\":\".*?\"", jsonencode(var.acme_cert))) ... but what you have is more readable

This is the standard algorithm for accomplishing a reconstruction of a nested map. Maybe one day in the future there will be an improvement, but for now this is the standard.

Your desired result discards the first level of nesting describing the individual certificate requests, and so this does seem like a good problem to solve using flatten.
The example you shared has essentially the same structure as the one in Flattening nested structures for for_each, albeit with two levels of nested lists instead of nested maps in that example, so your situation exactly matches the main goal of the flatten function.
